# Ubuntu 18.04 not seeing all ram

Tags: uefi, ram

I am experiencing something strange:
I have 12GB memory installed, UEFI recognises them, but Ubuntu only tells me that 8GB is available.

**Update 1**:  changing the banks does affect the output. It appears that Ubuntu 18.04 is only detecting what sits in bank 1 & 2. If I do ABAB setup I only have 6GB, when I do AABB I get 8 GB when I put them in BBAA I have only 4GB. Yet what I find really daunting is that the kernel is receiving 12GB in that first line.

Now, I discovered the following: When I do a Journalctl |grep memory.*available I get the following output

```
Jun 26 23:08:29 kodi-desktop kernel: Memory: 12159232K/12538600K available (8613K kernel code, 1335K rwdata, 4028K rodata, 1484K init, 1284K bss, 379368K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Jun 28 15:30:36 kodi-desktop kernel: Memory: 3901276K/4149992K available (8613K kernel code, 1335K rwdata, 4028K rodata, 1484K init, 1284K bss, 248716K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Jul 03 20:04:16 kodi-desktop kernel: Memory: 3901276K/4149992K available (8613K kernel code, 1335K rwdata, 4028K rodata, 1484K init, 1284K bss, 248716K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Jul 03 20:25:09 kodi-desktop kernel: Memory: 8030040K/8344296K available (8613K kernel code, 1335K rwdata, 4028K rodata, 1484K init, 1284K bss, 314256K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Jul 03 20:32:45 kodi-desktop kernel: Memory: 8014192K/8344296K available (12300K kernel code, 2473K rwdata, 4272K rodata, 2408K init, 2416K bss, 330104K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

Notice how the first memory in available changes. The last line actually say 12300K kernel core. but the available seems less.
Any ideas on how to make all 12GB available?

I am running docker on this, but considering this is coming from the boot, it should not interfere as docker is not loaded.

I am running 4.15.0-54-generic

output of free -m -t -t -h

```
                  total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        2.4G        1.8G         13M        3.5G        5.0G
Low:           7.7G        5.9G        1.8G
High:            0B          0B          0B
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G
Total:          11G        2.4G        5.8G

Output of 
lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode                               -s baseboard-manufacturer
    product: To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
05/31/2016
970 Pro3 R2.0
ASRock
```

Maybe important to know:
This is an dist-upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (LTS) I got the full 12GB on 16.04. This is my home server, so I am not really in the liberty to reinstall.

UEFI does show 12GB to.

```
 lshw -C memory
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P2.80
       date: 05/31/2016
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 4032KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi                                                        usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 288KiB
       capacity: 288KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: e
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 12GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: F3-1600C11-4GIS
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: A1_DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: F3-1600C11-4GIS
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: A1_DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: 9905402-421.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 2
          serial: 6F1E114B
          slot: A1_DIMM2
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: 9905402-421.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 3
          serial: 701E074B
          slot: A1_DIMM3
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

My graphics part is a GTX1050. so no memory from the RAM used.
*Computer built*
5 x 1TB WD disk for ZFS Raid5 (4+1 spare)
1 x ssd 128GB for system disk
1 x 1TB Disk for backup
FX6300 CPU + zalman cooler
Pro970 ASRock Mainboard
4 RAM stick (2x2 + 2x4 GB)
Coolermaster 280 case
2 120mm fans
GTX1050

Kind regards

Comment: What is the output of the command `free -m -l -t -h` ?

Comment: Please also run `sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer` and paste the result, along with the other command to run, in yr question after clicking [edit]. Also please put 2 space characters after each end of line before you press Enter so what you post formats well onscreen.  Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.

Comment: Have you allocated 4G to video RAM? Do you have unequal sizes of memory sticks installed? Laptop or Desktop? Show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: @K7AAY re: "new comments can shove old comments off screen". Not true.

Comment: Regarding your update, I'd recommend placing the 4G sticks into A2 and B2, as per the info in my answer. Leave the 2G sticks out for now. Purchase two more similar 4G sticks, and insert them into A1 and B1. The manual clearly calls out that all four sticks have to be the same, when using four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check your BIOS version using `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. It'll probably show P2.80. Then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS.
- It looks like your RAM may be configured incorrectly.

Most desktop motherboards have 2 memory channels/banks, sometimes even 3 or 4. These channels/banks are printed on the motherboard, and normally look like A/B/C/D. Actual slot numbers range from 0 to 8, or maybe even more. Memory should be installed in quantities equal to the number of channels for optimum performance and to take advantage of memory interleaving.

Your memory all appears to be in channel A, instead of equal size RAM sticks appearing in A/B.

Take out your memory sticks. **Take the 4G sticks and place them into slots** <strike>A0 and B0. Take the 2G sticks and place them into slots A1 and B1.</strike> **A2 and B2. Leave the 2G sticks out all together. This motherboard requires that all four sticks have to be the exact same when all four slots are filled. Purchase 2 additional (similar as others) 4G sticks and insert them into slots A1 and B1.**

Then view the configuration in the BIOS. Observe the reported memory in Ubuntu.

- Then download and run a memory diagnostic. Go to **http://www.memtest.org** or **https://www.memtest86.com/** (use the second link to get the latest free version), and download/run memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the tests to confirm good memory.

**Update #1:**

From the web site...

```
Memory

- Dual Channel DDR3 memory technology
- 4 x DDR3 DIMM slots
- Supports DDR3 2100(OC)/1866(OC)*/1800(OC)*/1600(OC)*/1333/1066/800 non-ECC, un-buffered memory
- Max. capacity of system memory: 64GB*

*1866/1800/1600MHz memory speed is supported depend on the AM3/AM3+ CPU you adopt. For detail CPU specification, please refer AMD official website.
```

Does your RAM meet these specs?

**Update #2:**

From the manual... **It looks like you need 4 identical RAM sticks**...

[image]

Comment: hi, as my bios and both the linux kernel seem to detect the 12GB, I wonder what the  dual channel has to do with the reporting of only 8GB. What I wonder in the first line . When I swap the banks, It only sees 6 GB (as if the linux kernel only wants to use the first 2 banks and not the full 4 banks) On the mainboard it is A-A / B-B for that matter.

Comment: @SteveCaster see Update #2. Also check your BIOS for an update.

Comment: frak... Strange that it did seem to work on Ubuntu 16.04. Although doubting now. Might be I just discovered this.

Comment: Unfortunately no BIOS update :(

Comment: @SteveCaster if you remove the 2G sticks, and put the 4G sticks into A2/B2, I'll bet you still see 8G total RAM... but that would be correct... and lshw would probably show dual channel usage.

Comment: If you run lshw as "sudo lshw" you will see more detailed output and may find that both banks become visible. For example see 8GB running as "lshw" and 16GB with detail of the individual banks as "sudo lshw" as I did in my case.