# RAM missing for Ubuntu, present for Windows

Tags: ram

I am moving a machine from Windows to Ubuntu.

Machine has 4 DDR3 memory sockets, 4 GB each.

After installing Ubuntu desktop 18.04 64 bits, I find only 8 GB, using "free command",
but "dmidecode -t 17" command and also "lshw -c memory" command show 16 GB are detected.

I read here it is the BIOS limiting the size

> > > [Ubuntu on x64 sees 2G of 12G RAM installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974543/ubuntu-on-x64-sees-2g-of-12g-ram-installed)

But I am 99 % sure the 16 GB RAM were used by Windows.

I have been to the BIOS and find nothing related to configuration.

Bios version is 980DE3/U3S3 and here it says it supports up to 32 GB :

> > > https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/980de3u3s3/

Any ideas on what can I do ?
Thanks.

As requested, the data in proper format : (sorry)

PS1.-

```
nicolau@mars:~/sebas/_local_tinet_files$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P1.00
       date: 02/10/2015
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 1984KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 288KiB
       capacity: 288KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 13
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: 99U5584-005.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: 53741D0B
          slot: DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: 99U5584-005.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: 0CF51E12
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: 99U5584-005.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 2
          serial: 3E631E0F
          slot: DIMM2
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: KHX1600C10D3/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 3
          serial: 7D771D73
          slot: DIMM3
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

PS2.- Ryzen processor - here is the output of provided command :

```
nicolau@mars:~$ sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep -i version
    Version: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor
```

PS3.- my RAM "99U5584-005.A00LF" is not in the list, all 4 cards are Kingston.

PS4.- memtest says "OK" - found all 4x 4GB memory, identified perfect 2 "models" :

[image: memtest OK, 4 rams detected]

PS5.- BIOS version

```
nicolau@mars:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version 
P1.00
```

I know there is a v2 from here

```
https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/980de3u3s3/#BIOS
```

but I am a bit scared to do BIOS upgrade

PS6.- I have removed the "different" RAM and now have 12 GB :

```
nicolau@mars:~$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       12252164     2002444     9001504      105012     1248216     9872704
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148
```

Guess this indicates ...

a) I stay with 12 GB with 3 cards

b) I buy 2 identical cards to get up to 16 GB

I am using Ubutnu at home, not too many APPs running simultaneous - guess I will stay with (a)

What is your opinion ?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155742/ubuntu-18-04-not-seeing-all-ram  Also, try setting the RAM in BIOS to Unganged Mode if it is not set.  These are only suggestions.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. What processor do you have? What make/model RAM? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but `lshw` command output in comments are unreadable... please delete the prior comment, redo the command, and edit those details into your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Sebastia.Net put that information into your question as **an edit to the question** so it formats it right

Comment: What Ryzen processor do you have?

Comment: Processor = `sudo dmidecode -t 4 | grep -i version`

Comment: RAM = you have 1/4 DIMMs that don't match. Vendor = Kingston

Comment: @heynnema - good morning. Why you say "1/4" is Kingston ? All 4 memory cards are Kingston, AFASI-see

Comment: @heynnema - 3 are product "99U5584-005.A00LF", one is "KHX1600C10D3/8G"

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I'll be interested to see what `memtest` says. I updated my answer with info about the memory.

Comment: @heynnema - I agree it is not good to have different RAMs. Will try to find a new (identical) pair ...

Comment: @heynnema - memtest : burned an USB from Linux, does not boot (blank screen). Burned an USB from Windows, does not boot (blank screen). Seems USB is not "bootable" ...

Comment: @heynnema - one question - why do we use memtest86 if it is a 64-bit machine ?

Comment: @Sebastia.Net As of version 5, memtest is 64-bit. You can also check http://www.memtest.org

Comment: @heynnema - ok, before I was a "https://www.memtest86.com/", now "http://www.memtest.org/", I am on it

Comment: @heynnema - updated question PS4 - memtest86+ says memory is ok - any ideas now ?

Comment: @Sebastia.Net Did you notice if memtest found all 16G? Next step to try... carefully remove the odd DIMM from "bank 3/slot DIMM3" and see if Ubuntu sees 8G or 12G.

Comment: @Sebastia.Net Please see Update #2 in my answer.

Comment: @Sebastia.Net Did you already do the BIOS update?

Comment: @heynnema - BIOS update - I am a bit scared to do that. To have 8 GB instead of 16 is still alive, but an error on BIOS update and I am dead. I am gonna read how it is done and have a thought about it. Do you think it can fix the problem ? I would prefer to buy 2 identical RAMs and plug them ... What is your opinion ? Their page says "We do not recommend users to update the BIOS if their system is already running normally", jejeje

Comment: @heynnema - remove "different" RAM - that is an easy and excelent idea. Will do it tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Sebastia.Net Yes, the BIOS update can be a little scary, especially for someone who has never done it successfully. It's actually quite easy. re: *"We do not recommend users to update the BIOS if their system is already running normally"*... ALL manufacturer's web sites say that... and as you note... your system is NOT running normally. Can it fix your memory problem? Sure. Guaranteed? No. My BIOS update instructions also say to do good backups before doing the BIOS update.

Comment: @heynnema - thanks for your support, mr heynnema - today I went to dentist with some urgency, so RAM removal will be done tomorrow morning.

Comment: @heynnema - 1 memory card removed, results in updated question (PS6)

Comment: @Sebastia.Net If you can find a DIMM that exactly matches the other three, then you'll have 16G. Good job! I updated my answer again.

Comment: @heynnema - man, thanks a lot. I been around here few years now. Never saw such an attention as yours. Really appreciate it and you time. Should you never come to Barcelona (Catalonia), just let me know - you'll remember those days, for sure - wine and paella (:-))

Comment: @Sebastia.Net Glad I could help! Keep the wine and paella ready...

Comment: @heynnema - you did "above and beyond" and I like to be host, jajaja

Comment: @Sebastia.Net Remember to work up the courage to update the BIOS. Do backups first.

Comment: @heynnema - I evaluate "pros" and "cons" - now that I have 12 GB, what shall I win if I update BIOS ?

Comment: @Sebastia.Net If you check the link to the BIOS update page, you'll see that many of the updates between 1.00 and 2.00 indicate improved memory compatibility.

Comment: @heynnema - I see what you say, but thats not my case I'd say - if I get 2 identical cards, I'm sure to climb to 16 GB without BIOS update (:-)) ... in aliexpress righ now .. good prices

Comment: @Sebastia.Net re:"f I get 2 identical cards, I'm sure to climb to 16 GB without BIOS update" not necessarily true. Anyway... keep the BIOS update in mind. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASRock 980DE3/U3S3

`User Manual` is [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/980de3u3s3/#Manual).

You have BIOS version P1.00, which is very old.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 2.00, dated 9/23/2015, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/980de3u3s3/#BIOS).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Ryzen/Memory**

AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility issues.

Review the `CPU Support List` at [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/980de3u3s3/#CPU) and determine your Ryzen model/series product.

Review the `Memory Support List` at [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/amd/980de3u3s3/#Memory) and determine if your current memory is supported.

**Update #1:** In reviewing the output of `sudo lshw -C memory`, we see that your 4 memory DIMMs are not the same. Three are Kingston product "99U5584-005.A00LF", one is Kingston product "KHX1600C10D3/8G". The specs for the "KHX1600C10D3/8G" are different than the other three. That's enough to cause your problem. We'll see what `memtest` has to say about it.

**Update #3:**

We pulled out the odd KHX1600C10D3/8G DIMM and now the system properly shows 12G RAM. Will need to purchase a replacement 4G DIMM that matches the remaining three DIMMs.

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #2:**

From the ASRock User Manual, we see how to configure the RAM for dual-channel operation. See below...

[image]

[image]

Comment: do we WANT to have "dual-channel operation" ?

Comment: +1 This is a truly excellent answer.

Comment: @Sebastia.Net Yes, we always want to try and achieve dual-channel operation, as it interleaves memory, and gives a significant performance advantage... but you must have 2 or 4 exactly identical DIMMs to allow it to work.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks!